# Toggle text input when RadioBox input checked

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I'm trying to connect between radiobox when it is clicked, to toggle (I mean automaticly click on) the text input

So, I did the following:

```
<input type="radio" name="t" value=""  onclick="<!-- Connect to text input !-->"> Radio 1
<input type="text" id="x" name="xx" placeholder="Test">
```

How should I go about this ?

Comment: You mean you want to set the focus to the text box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set focus to the text box, you can use:

```
<input type="radio" name="t" value=""  onclick="document.getElementById('x').focus();"> Radio 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do, you have to use `document.querySelector('#x').focus()`, where `x` is the "id" of text input.

```
<input type="radio" name="t" value=""  onclick="document.querySelector('#x').focus()"> Radio 1
<input type="text" id="x" name="xx" placeholder="Test">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this with jquery:

```
<input type="radio">
<input type="text">
** <script>
  $('input[type="radio"]:checked + input[type="text"]').focus();
</script>**
```